# Calculating average, min, max of a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, 2d

I'm supposed to write a program to read and fill an array with 5 student IDs and their grades then print the average, min and max grades with the IDs of the students, an example could be:
Student 1: 111 56
Student 2: 222 98
Student 3: 333 90
Student 4: 444 68
Student 5: 555 88
Average: 80
Rank#1: 222 98
Rank#5: 111 56
My program is giving me messed up values (Average is 328.4, rank#1: 444 555, rank#5: 555 88) along with a debug error (Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupter), here it is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void avg(double a[4][1]);
void minMax(double a[4][1]);
void main () {
    double a[4][1];
    cout << "Enter 5 students' IDs and marks:\n";
    int studentNum = 1;
    for (int r=0; r<5; r++) {
        cout << "Student" << studentNum << ": ";
        studentNum++;
        for (int c=0; c<2; c++) 
            cin >> a[r][c]; }
    avg(a);
    minMax(a); }
void avg(double a[4][1]){
    double sum=0.0;
    for (int r=0; r<5; r++) {
        for (int c=1; c<2; c++) // does not include the ID column
            sum = sum + a[r][c]; }
    double avg = sum/5; // number of students = 5
    cout << "Average: " << avg << endl; } 
void minMax (double a[4][1]) {
    double min = a[0][1];
    double max = a[0][1];
    int minID = a[0][0];
    int maxID = a[0][0];
    for (int r=0; r<5; r++) {
        for (int c=1; c<2; c++) {
            if (a[r][c] < min){
                min = a[r][c];
                minID = a[r][0]; }
            if (a[r][c] > max){
                max = a[r][c];
                maxID = a[r][0]; } } } 
    cout << "Rank#1: " << maxID << " " << max << endl;
    cout << "Rank#5: " << minID << " " << min << endl; }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Removing your code makes below answers useless, don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

The error is :

```
 double a[4][1];
```

It should be:

```
double a[5][2];
```